# iText - render html dropdown to editable pdf using c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, acrofields

I have Dropdown list in HTM page. i want to convert this on editable pdf using iText Library. I Have to set AcroForms/field. it is unable to render dropdown html (select/option) tag.

expectation : Dropdown should be editable in PDF.

'

```
       String dest = "h2PMethod1_1.pdf";
       PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest);
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();            
       iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
       converterProperties.SetCreateAcroForm(true);
        iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
        Document document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmlString, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
        document.Close();
```

'

Comment: As @artyom-minsk wrote, the `SetCreateAcroForm` mode is not supported for `select` elements as of latest pdfHTML version `3.0.5`. This is the only form element that doesn't work the same way as other form elements in acroform conversion mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like select tag attributes isn't supported in current version of HtmlConverter.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.